Postman: add header in a pre-request script
I have a "pre-request script" in Postman to get the token and add information in a collection variable and it works fine.
I create my request as shown below:
01 const echoPostRequest = {
02   url: pm.collectionVariables.get("token_url"),
03   method: 'POST',
04   header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
05 };

Then later I use pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) to submit it and it is working as expected.
Now, I need to replace the single value in header (line 04 in the example above) and add multiple records in the header. I found that I can use pm.request.headers.add, but I'm struggling to find out how to add multiple header parameters within my constant echoPostRequest.
Does anyone know how could it be achieved?
I tried something like:
01 const echoPostRequest = {
02   url: pm.collectionVariables.get("token_url"),
03   method: 'POST',
04   pm.request.headers.add({
05                           'Content-Type':'application/json',
06                           'Authorization':pm.collectionVariables.get("secret")
07                         })
08 };

I tried other formats but none of them worked. I also have collection variables to add in the header.

The header key will accept an object.
const echoPostRequest = {
    url: pm.collectionVariables.get("token_url"),
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
};


It worked, thank you.
